# Conversion operator vs constructor from given type. Which is preferable?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm defining iterator types for my container and of course I want `iterator` to be convertible to `const_iterator`. But I'm not sure which is better/preferable:

Conversion operator in `iterator`

```
class iterator
{
    operator const_iterator();
};
```

or non-explicit constructor in `const_iterator`

```
class iterator
{
    // implementation
    friend class iterator; // hard to avoid this
};

class const_iterator
{
    const_iterator(iterator const &);
};
```

Are there any guidelines which way is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a casting operator only if it is possible to return the desired type without constructing a new object, or if its return is a simple data type. For example, if it were to return a const reference to a property within the class, then you should write it as a casting operator.

In all other cases, you should just write the appropriate constructor.

Comment: I have no doubt, but could you explain the reasons? Is this still true when taking into account that new C++ syntax provides explicit operators?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule:

There is almost ***never*** a good reason to provide **implicit conversion operators**; it is always ***preferable*** to use ***conversion constructors***. With implicit conversion operators you will seldom find them invoked when you don't expect and create unnecessary confusions.

***conversion constructors*** is also a better way since it lets you adheres you to the ***[Principle of least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).***

The only common exception to this rule is provide a conversion to a boolean type, so that objects (e.g., smart pointers) can be used in boolean contexts.

Comment: AFAIK both conversion operators and conversion constructors allow compiler to perform implicit conversions. Are they (operators and constructors) in some circumstances treated differently according to implicit conversions?

Comment: The linked principle is very generic. Could you give us a more technical explanation for your rule? Especially taking into account that new C++ syntax provides explicit operators?

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations let `iterator` inherit from `const_iterator`, and get the conversion for free.