# C++ - Competing cast/assignment

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

If I have 2 classes `A` and `B` and wish to implement conversion from `A` to `B`, I can see 2 possibilities.

---

## 1st possibility

```
class A {
    // Some attributes, methods
    operator B() const {
        // Conversion from A to B
    }
}

class B {
    // Some attributes, methods
}
```

---

## 2nd possibility

```
class A {
    // Some attributes, methods
}

class B {
    // Some attributes, methods
    B& operator =(const A& src) {
        // Conversion from A to B
    }
}
```

---

Both these methods allow to run the following code:

## Executed code

```
A instA;
B instB;

instB = instA; // Ok
```

---

Now let's imagine I implement both functions (cast to `B` in class `A` and `operator =` from `A` in class `B`:

## 3rd possibility

```
class A {
    // Some attributes, methods
    operator B() const {
        // Conversion from A to B - Code 1
    }
}

class B {
    // Some attributes, methods
    B& operator =(const A& src) {
        // Conversion from A to B - Code 2
    }
}
```

---

assuming *Code 1* and *Code 2* have the same effect (or even different effects, why not).

My questions are:

- If competing cast/assignment methods are provided, which one would be chosen first when doing implicit cast?
- Is there any interest implementing both competing cast/assignment methods?
- Perhaps this would even be a good idea to call `operator =` of class `B` in `B()` cast operator of class `A`?

Comment: Related, and possible duplicate: [Conversion operator vs constructor from given type. Which is preferable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095802/conversion-operator-vs-constructor-from-given-type-which-is-preferable)

Comment: @xskxzr Related definitely, duplicate no, my questions are multiple and go further.

Comment: Also related/dupe: [Conversion constructor vs. conversion operator: precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384007/conversion-constructor-vs-conversion-operator-precedence).

Answer (score 2):

> If competing cast/assignment methods are provided, which one would be chosen first when doing implicit cast?

Given the choices, the `operator=()` will be given the first preference since it does not require the argument, the RHS, to be converted.

> Is there any interest implementing both competing cast/assignment methods?

No. That's best avoided to prevent confusion.

> Perhaps this would even be a good idea to call `operator =` of class `B` in `B()` cast operator of class `A`?

If you must support both, then, yes, it would be a good idea to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the last point I really meant *in*, not *and*.
Another question: can you overload `operator =` of native types (int, long, etc) to set a conversion from your own class?

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois, If by that you mean `int i; B b; i = b;`, no you can't do that.

Comment: So how do you explain the execution of the following code?https://onlinegdb.com/S1nk_nZOG

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois, that is  not a `operator=` overload. It is a user defined conversion operator. Yes, the language definitely supports that.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I thought you were saying it wasn't possible to do `int i; B b; i = b;` in general.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois, no problem. It's good that we cleared up that confusion.